# How do I select all of the elements in a list that have children, using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have an arbitrarily deep list, like so:

```
<ul>
<li></li>
<li>
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li>
      <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Using jQuery, how can I select every li in the list that is *not* a leaf node.  In other words, I want to select all of the li elements that have children ULs.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
jQuery('li:has(ul)');
```

[More info about `:has`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/).

Comment: Beautiful.  jQuery to the rescue once again.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another alternative:

```
$('li ul').closest('li')
```

This is likely to be a fair bit faster than `:has` on modern browsers, since it'll use the native `querySelectorAll` method on the main selector. `:has` can't use native support since it's not a standard CSS selector but a jQuery extension.

Comment: I tried this vs. `$('li:has(ul)');` in Chrome and FF and the latter was around ~30% faster. I think this is less efficient than it seems on the surface. Whether or not the native selector engine is used, the selector is still parsed in reverse (AFAIK)... So, all `ul` elements are gotten and then each one's ancestor-chain is checked for an `li` element. Then... each conforming `ul` is submitted to the same routine with `closest()`...

Comment: So, to sum up, `li ul` is fast... but only if you actually want the `ul` elements. The call to `closest()` makes this solution less efficient than using `:has`.

Comment: I ran `$('li ul').closest('li').size()` and `$('li:has(ul)').size()` in a loop of 20000 against the example markup in the question. `closest` was between two to four times faster in browsers with Selectors-API support and about 10% slower in IE7.

Comment: Interesting. Admittedly, my tests were a little far fetched. I just changed it out and used the OP's markup -- now in FF they're almost identical, and Chrome shows yours as faster, albeit inconsistently.